# Mounting iso images to play on wine

Tags: 12.04, mount, wine, games, iso

I would very much like to be able to mount iso images on my file system while getting wine to detect them as if they were real cd/dvd images inside the cd/dvd drive. As of this day I haven't been able to do it with Furious Iso Mount or GMountIso. This is an issue when trying to play a game on wine: I can mount an image and install the game perfectly, but when it comes to play the game I get the "please insert your cdrom" message. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something about mounting; on Windows, I used Daemon Tools just fine.

Any clues?

Comment: Some games actually require you to use a Nocd/DVD crack to run the game, might just be the case.

Comment: Uri Herrera, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, is not the case.

Comment: Have you registered the mounted directory with `winecfg` as CD-ROM instead of a regular HDD?

Comment: Grumbel, it seems Wine does that automatically when I do the installation with the iso mounted; it's probably set when playonlinux requieres me to specify the location of the cdrom.

Comment: You could try `cdemu`; please see the answers [for this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278912/mount-an-iso-image-in-wine).